# how to get AccountAuthenticatorResponse input for many methods in AbstractAccountAuthenticator

Tags: android

In class AbstractAccountAuthenticator, many methods need a AccountAuthenticatorResponse input . It looks very important. Yet where to get the AccountAuthenticatorResponse parameter? I found it might be put into intent extra in addAccount method of AbstractAccountAuthenticator like below.

```
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType,
        String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    ............
}
```

Yet where is the "response" value from? I can't find any example on web.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/apps-for-android/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/authenticator/Authenticator.java.shtml) shows how to implement AbstractAccountAuthenticator but that alone is useless. You also need to extend [AccountAuthenticatorActivity](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.java.shtml),add this to the manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".mypackagename.AuthenticatorActivity"
    android:label="@string/signup">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" /> 
</activity>
```

In the res folder create a folder named "xml" and put a file named "authenticator.xml" inside put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="you.will.see.this.in.other.places"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"/>`
```

I think prefs is optional. You may also see AccountManager in the links

Comment: I am not sure of the flow, kind of a black box but if you implement the 4 things you should be fine